# Using Paypal in an iOS app for a subscription

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, subscription

I am reading a lot of stuff from the Internet, but I can't find any answer to this specific topic :

I am currently developing an iOS app for a French newspaper. They want me to add a Paypal feature to allow any user to take out a subscription to their newspaper. They don't want the newspaper to be readable on the device.

All they want is to get both user's name and address, and send the newspaper manually.

I can't properly define if Apple will allow me to publish such an app. So my questions are :
Will it be rejected by Apple if I add this feature ? Is it considered as a digital good or a hard good ?

Thank you so much for your replies.

Jérôme.

Comment: @jjboursier- you can only use inappPurchase in ios for that

Comment: @VivekSehrawat thank you for your quick reply. Will it be rejected too if I just ask for user's email address and send him the form he will have to fill and send by post ?